# How to insert a scrollbar and a form in a notebook widget with python and tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am really new to python and currently I am trying to design a form using tkinter. I am stuck trying to insert an scrollbar and a form in a notebook since I haven't found an answer to my question, and it is simple "How can I insert a scrollbar and a form in a notebook tkinter widget?"... As you can see is simple for you, but not for a newbie like me!

However, this is what I have done so far, fortunately it does show the scrollbar, but it crashes when I try insert the form into the notebook!

Note: My python version is Python 2.7.3 with EPD_free 7.3-2 (32-bit)

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import * 
from ttk import *   
import tkMessageBox 
import ttk  
import Tkinter as tk 

root = Tk()
root.title("Model_A")
root.resizable(0,0)

# start of Notebook (multiple tabs)
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
notebook.pressed_index = None

#Child Frames
ContainerOne = Frame(notebook)
ContainerOne.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
ContainerTwo = Frame(notebook)
ContainerTwo.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
ContainerThree = Frame(notebook)
ContainerThree.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
ContainerFour = Tkinter.Frame(notebook)
ContainerFour.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

#Create the pages
notebook.add(ContainerOne, text='Mode A')
notebook.add(ContainerTwo, text='Mode B')
notebook.add(ContainerThree, text='Mode C')
notebook.add(ContainerFour, text='Mode D')

canvas = Canvas(ContainerOne, width=200, height=400)
scroll = Scrollbar(ContainerOne, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,100,1000))
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas = Canvas(ContainerTwo, width=200, height=400)
scroll = Scrollbar(ContainerTwo, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,100,1000))
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

canvas = Canvas(ContainerThree, width=200, height=400)
scroll = Scrollbar(ContainerThree, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,100,1000))
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas = Canvas(ContainerFour, width=200, height=400)
scroll = Scrollbar(ContainerFour, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,100,1000))
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
frame = Frame(canvas, width=200, height=1000)
canvas.create_window(100, 500, window=frame)

frameOne = None  

def defocus(event):
    event.widget.master.focus_set()    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ContainerOne= Tkinter.Label(notebook, text=" 1. Enter Main Details: ", font=("fixedsys", "16","bold italic"))
        frameOne.grid(row=2, columnspan=7, sticky='W', \
                 padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

#Component Selection
componentComb= ttk.Combobox(ContainerOne, width="19")
componentComb = Combobox(ContainerOne, state="readonly", values=("A", "B", "C"))
componentComb.grid(column=4, row=4, columnspan="5", sticky="nswe")
componentComb.set("Main Selection")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10):

If you take a look at the [options of the Notebook widget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Notebook.html), you can see that neither `yview` nor `yscrollcommand` are present. Besides, Frame widgets aren't scrollable either.

What you can do is to create a Canvas widget with a Scrollbar inside your `frameOne`, and then add a Frame to the canvas with [`create_window`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method).

```
root = Tk()
root.resizable(0,0)
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
notebook.pressed_index = None
container = Frame(notebook)
container.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
notebook.add(container, text='Mode A')

canvas = Canvas(container, width=200, height=400)
scroll = Scrollbar(container, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,100,1000))
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

frame = Frame(canvas, bg='white', width=200, height=1000)
canvas.create_window(100, 500, window=frame)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dear A.rodas, thank you very much for your prompt response. I am trying to make what you said, I will let you know how it was. Thank you.

Comment: Dear A.Rodas, I have done what you said, but I don't know what I am making wrong since it is no working good... I would like to post what I have done so far but I don't know where to put the updates. Can you tell me how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Hector I've just added a sample program. If you have any doubt, please let me know it.

Comment: Dear A. Rodas, Thanks for the sample program. It does work perfect,but when I try to add a form into this notebook it just crashes. I would like to give you the new code, but I don't know where I can put it in. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Hector Please feel free to edit your question to add the new code, it can be of help to understand and solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the problem I had with python and tkinter inserting form into a notebook as well as a scrollbar. I want to thank @A.Rodas for his kind help.

This is my code, hope you find it useful!

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import tkMessageBox
import math 
import ttk 
import Tkinter as tk

def defocus(event):
    event.widget.master.focus_set()

# start of GUI code
root = Tk()
root.title("Model A")
root.resizable(0,0)

# start of Notebook (multiple tabs)
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
notebook.pressed_index = None

# Child frames
ContainerOne = Frame(notebook)
ContainerOne.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
ContainerTwo = Frame(notebook)
ContainerTwo.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

# Create the pages
notebook.add(ContainerOne, text='Mode A')
notebook.add(ContainerTwo, text='Mode B')

canvas1 = Canvas(ContainerOne, width=1200, height=450)
scroll = Scrollbar(ContainerOne, command=canvas1.yview)
canvas1.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,100,1000))
canvas1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas2 = Canvas(ContainerTwo, width=1200, height=450)
scroll = Scrollbar(ContainerTwo, command=canvas2.yview)
canvas2.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,100,1000))
canvas2.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

frameOne = Frame(canvas1, width=800, height=450)
canvas1.create_window(250, 125, window=frameOne)

frameTwo = Frame(canvas2, width=800, height=450)
canvas2.create_window(200, 140, window=frameTwo)

# Main Frame

#Close Application Button
def quit(root):
    root.destroy()

ttk.Button(root, text="Close Application", command=lambda root=root:quit(root)).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Main Part
    stepOne = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frameOne, text=" 1. Enter Main Details: ", font=("fixedsys", "16","bold italic"))
    stepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=5, sticky='nsew', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
    stepTwo = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frameOne, text=" 2. Calculate AP : ", font=("fixedsys", "16","bold italic"))
    stepTwo.grid(row=2, columnspan=7, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

# First Step Starts 

# Component Selection
componentComb= ttk.Combobox(stepOne, width="19")
componentComb = Combobox(stepOne, state="readonly", values=("CDA", "VHS", "DVD"))
componentComb.grid(column=4, row=0, columnspan="5", sticky="nswe")
componentComb.set("Component Selection")

# Temperature Selection
tempComb = ttk.Combobox(stepOne, width="12")
tempComb = Combobox(stepOne, state="readonly", values=("-40", "-30", "-20","-10", "0",))
tempComb.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan="2", sticky="w")
tempComb.set("Temperature Selection")

# Second Step Starts
inEncLbl = Tkinter.Label(stepTwo, text="Oxide:")
inEncLbl.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

inEncTxt = Tkinter.Entry(stepTwo, width=6)
inEncTxt.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w', pady=2)

outEncLbl = Tkinter.Label(stepTwo, text="Density Rate (DR):")
outEncLbl.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=5, pady=2)

outEncTxt = Tkinter.Entry(stepTwo, width=6)
outEncTxt.grid(row=2, column=7,sticky='w', pady=2)

#End Code
root.mainloop()
```